# Проверка поля input

Tags: html, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/Akt85/ - код.

html:

```
<!--Изначально -->
<!--val2  число от 5000 или 10000 - любое которое введёт пользователь-->
Random value <input type="text" id="val2" /><br />
<!--val1 - значения 31,91,181,275,365 -->
SELECT
<select id='val1'>
    <option value='31'>use 100500</option>
    <option value='91'>why not 800</option>
    <option value='181'>i mean 777</option>
    <option value='275'>why not 800</option>
    <option value='365'>i mean 777</option>
</select><br /> 
YESNO1
<input type='radio' name='val3' value='0' />
<input type='radio' name='val3' value='1' />
<br />
YESNO2
<input type='radio' name='val4' value='0' />
<input type='radio' name='val4' value='1' /><br />
<button type="button" id='filterButton'>filter it!</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

js:

```
var myvar = [  
    {name:"data1",val1:31,val2:3,val3:true,val4:false},  
    {name:"data2",val1:91,val2:1,val3:false,val4:false},  
    {name:"data3",val1:181,val2:2,val3:false,val4:true},  
    {name:"data2",val1:275,val2:1,val3:false,val4:false},  
    {name:"data3",val1:365,val2:2,val3:false,val4:true},  
];
   document.getElementById('filterButton').onclick = function(){
        var filter = [];
        filter.push(document.getElementById('val1').options[document.getElementById('val1').selectedIndex].value);
       filter.push(document.getElementById('val2').value);
       filter.push(rbvalue('val3')=='1');
       filter.push(rbvalue('val4')=='1');
        var filtered_data = [];
       var data_accepted = true;
        for(i=0;i<myvar.length;i++){
          data_accepted = true;
          for(j=0;j<filter.length;j++){
            if(filter[j]!=='' && filter[j]!=myvar[i][('val'+(j+1))]){
              data_accepted = false;
            }

          }
        if(data_accepted){
           filtered_data.push(myvar[i]);
        }
   }
       var container = document.getElementById('container');
       container.innerHTML = '';
       for(i=0;i<filtered_data.length;i++){
           container.innerHTML+=filtered_data[i].name+'<br />';
       }
  };

function rbvalue(html_name){
    var undefined,default_value,i,rb_collection = document.getElementsByName(html_name);
    if(rb_collection!==undefined){
        default_value = rb_collection[0].value;
    }
    for(i=0;i<rb_collection.length;i++){
        if(rb_collection[i].checked){
            return rb_collection[i].value;
        }
    }
    return default_value;
}
```

Подскажите, не могу сообразить как проверить поле инпут на наличие цифры, например если оно пустое то val2 == 0, а если с цифрой, то val2 == 1, 
и что бы эта еденица передовалась в фильтр,  и он отрабатывал свой код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам поможет функция js - [typeof](http://javascript.ru/typeof)
и на основе этого можно написать функцию для проверки на число:

```
function isNumber(n) {
   return typeof n === 'number' && n % 1 == 0;
}
```

Для строки можно написать аналогичную функцию

Comment: не поможет, т.к. value для инпутов всегда будет string.

Comment: да, действительно. Тогда играться с parseInt или регулярками

Comment: @Yura Ivanov @Barton  а можно вместо поля "data1" что бы выскакивал определённый select поле - такое реально?

Comment: додумал как селект вставить

Comment: @Yura Ivanov @Barton $('input').keyup(function(){
var nondigs=/[^\d]/g, val=$(this).val();
$(this).val(val.replace(nondigs,''));
}); - такая ф-ция же подойтет ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_int_field_value(n)
{
    if( is_empty(n) ) return 0;
    if( !/^\d+$/.test(n) ) 
    {
       alert("Wrong!"); return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Реализация проверки строки на "пусто" (is_empty()) - на своё усмотрение.

Answer (score 0):

выражение с помощью которого можно выполнить проверку:

```
/^\d+$/.test( INPUTVALUE )
```